# Variable Name in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable name called  `A_flag (1=Y,0=N)` . However, when I try to rename this variable, SAS says that it can't find the variable.

Is the variable name  `A_flag (1=Y,0=N)`  or  `A_flag`  ?

Comment: Variable names can't contain characters other than alphanumeric and underscores. What's the context, i.e. how are you defining and referencing it?

Comment: @AlexA.: In the proc contents procedure, the variable name is A_flag(1=Y, 0=N) and I am trying to perform a statistical test using this variable.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the variable _label_ rather than the variable _name_? It isn't possible for that to be the variable name.

Comment: @AlexA.: How would I get the variable name?

Comment: Do `ods select variables;` then run `proc contents` on your dataset. The variable name should be listed in the Variable column (leftmost column in table) and the label, if there is one, should be in the Label column (rightmost column in table).

Comment: In the Explorer window, double click Libraries, then double-click the library this dataset is in. When you right-click the dataset, choose View Columns. Scoll to the right to see if the text you are viewing is the variable's label, not its name. The name is in the left-most column.

Answer (score 5):

If the variablename really is "A_flag (1=Y,0=N)", then you need to refer to it as "A_flag (1=Y,0=N)"n.
E.g:

```
proc freq;
    tables "A_flag (1=Y,0=N)"n;
run;
```

You need the validvarname=any option set in order for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

That is likely a variable *label*, not a variable *name*.  If you are in display manager SAS (not Enterprise Guide), go into the View menu when you have a dataset open and select "Column Names" instead of "Column Labels".  That will show you the real variable name.

If it is a variable name, it probably came in with Enterprise Guide's default setting of `options validvarname=any` and a proc import from Excel.  If that's the case, I suggest adding to either your configuration file or just to the top line of your program:

```
options validvarname=v7;
```

Then run the `proc import` again and it will properly import the name as a legal SAS variable name without the name literal syntax Stig refers to (which is also a fine solution, but it can be tedious to use that.)